# Looking for a full list of jQuery event types

Tags: jquery, events, dom-events

Where I can find a complete list of all jQuery supported events (like `click`, `mouseup` etc) with some explanations when they are triggered? I am looking for those that can be binded:

```
$('#foo').bind('click', handler);
```

For example I just found out by accident that there is `paste` event but I can't find any references to it anywhere in their docs. What else is there?

Comment: The bind() method was deprecated in version 3.0. Use the on() method instead. Following is a link to the jquery on() method:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A non exhaustive list is at http://api.jquery.com/category/events/.  There are more DOM events supported through `.bind()` and `.live()`.  Those functions can assign a handler to any standard DOM event, most of which are listed along with compatibility tables at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/

> The .bind() method is the primary means of attaching behavior to a document. All JavaScript event types, such as focus, mouseover, and resize, are allowed for eventType.

---

As of jQuery 1.7, you should use `.on()` in place of `.live()` and `.bind()`.

Comment: All bind events is what I am looking for (not shortcut functions). Maybe I should rephrase my question.

Comment: @serg555: I added a quirksmode.org link, most (if not, all) events are listed there along with compatibility tables for each browser.  Note that Opera doesn't support the `paste` event.

Comment: After taking a closer look it seems pretty outdated. For example it says `mouseleave` is working only in IE but it is not true.

Comment: @serg555: actually, `mouseleave` is implemented by jQuery, it is not a standard event.  Firefox and Chrome do not support it, I haven't checked Safari and Opera.  jQuery provides this event in those browsers.  you are right, though, some of the quirksmode.org stuff is outdated.

Comment: I need a function to run on an a classed element when it's either 1) it's loaded or 2) it's shoved in the page via ajax, I tried `on('ready', '.my-class', handler)`, but it didn't work.

Comment: This answer is not really up to date. `touch` events are not listed for example.

Answer (score 12):

MDN has a good overview of majority of the standard and non-standard events

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events

Answer (score 3):

You can check out the full list of jQuery events: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

But regarding the `paste` event you mentioned, jQuery can also bind to standard DOM events. A good list is provided by MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old. But for the sake of giving an updated and complete answer to this question.

The shortcut methods are **always named the same** as the event names used in any of the on()/bind()/live() methods.

So if you want to use any shortcut event feature but with on()/bind()/live() you can just take the **method name**, ommit the brackets and put it in quotes like so: **"eventname"/'eventname'**. They should behave the same.

So for example: .dblclick() -> 'dblclick' =>

```
$('a').on('dblclick', function() {  
    console.log("I got double clicked");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ is a complete list of event methods. (Yes I know I'm not the only one pointing to this site but together with my explanation it actually is a complete list of events for 'on'/'live'/'bind')

If you have the chance to use on() you should do so since on() does the same and all calls to 'bind' and 'live' actually call the 'on' function. Here is  more prove about this: [What's the difference between `on` and `live` or `bind`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind)

Also some people asked about the touch (mobile) events. I generally recommend to get used to the on() event method because according to the [jQuery mobile documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/) this is the only way to register touch events on html elements, which is on par with jQuery's future api plans to remove bind()/live() and all the shortcut event methods.

Answer (score -1):

This page lists all events *that work in all browsers* to my knowledge. You will not find the "paste" event here, because, as others pointed it out, it doesn't work in all browsers.

http://www.authenticsociety.com/jquery/list-all-jquery-events.html

Comment: This is wrong: 
`.mouseup()` : Mouse pointer is over an element at any time while the mouse button is up

Comment: This link is now dead.