# jQuery on() Event Binding

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between `on` and `live` or `bind`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind)

I've been noticing people referring to jQuery's `.on()` method to bind events. I looked up the documentation and it seems like it is new as of version 1.7. I was looking around and I was unable to find why I should use it and how it's different from just `.bind()`. Can I use `.on()` all the time now or is it for specific cases?

If anyone has any input or links explaining the difference, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `on` for all event bindings now. As the documentation states:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method provides all functionality required
>   for attaching event handlers.

You can use it as you would have used `bind`:

```
$(elem).on("click", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

You can also use it as you would have used `delegate`:

```
$(elem).on("click", "selector", function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This blogpost discusses it to some extent: http://blog.jquery.com/2011/09/28/jquery-1-7-beta-1-released/