# JQuery code not working at a button click?

Tags: jquery, css, buttonclick

I have 3 buttons inside div's tages as below.

```
<div id="make_larger">
<button type="button">Large</button> 
</div>
<div id="make_small">
<button type="button">Smaller</button> 
</div>
<div id="make_normal">
<button type="button">Normal</button> 
</div>
```

I want when i will click on "Large" button its color should be change to blue(using .selected class of css for it) .Jquery code is as below.

```
$('#make_larger').bind('click', function () {
        $('body').addClass('large');
        $('body').removeClass('normal');
        $('body').removeClass('smaller');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

     });
```

But it is not working.Color is not being change.
Why?

Any help please.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png is also a good explanation for what you need to start doing, OP :)

Comment: Could you also post your css. I believe that you are adding class to div, try adding it to button inside div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change last line to

```
$(this).children('button').addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="make_larger">
    <button type="button">Large</button>
</div>
<div id="make_small">
    <button type="button">Smaller</button>
</div>
<div id="make_normal">
    <button type="button">Normal</button>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    .selected{background:blue}
</style>
```

**jQUERY**

```
$('#make_larger').click(function() {
     $('#make_larger button').addClass('selected');
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/mRwMt/10/

Comment: Or `$('button', this).addClass('selected');`

Answer (score 0):

you give the containing div the class selected, not the button. See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AFNJ9/.

ofcoure you can do something with css like:
`.selected button {background:blue;}` which will make the background blue of the button.

In my opionion it's nice to use 'on': [What's the difference between `on` and `live` or `bind`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind)