# How to clearInterval() in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a wall post like Facebook. I need to refresh the content div after every ten seconds and the div shouldn't refresh while the user is typing a comment. The content is reloading but is not stopping. Actually, I want to stop it when i click `id = 'comments_option'`.

I tried this and called the function reload(uid) at `$(document).ready`

```
var intervalId = null;

function reload(uid) {
    intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        var ol = $('#home_list');
        var start = ol.children().length;

        $.post('ajax/reloadhome.php', {
            uid: uid,
            start: start
        }, function (data) {
            $('#buzzfetch ul').html(data);
        });
    }, 5000);


    $('#comments_option').click(function () {

        clearInterval(intervalId);

    });
}
```

Comment: and what happened when you tried it?

Comment: as i mentioned ... it is reloading again and again .. i want to stop it when user click #comments_option

Comment: Is `var intervalId` defined _inside_ or _outside_ `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: is `reload(uid)` used only once?

Comment: It should be correct as is, but I'd declare "var intervalId" directly in the "reload" function.

Comment: is `#comments_option` inside of `#buzzfetch ul`? If so, you will have to bind your click event every time it is replaced.

Comment: it is inside #buzzfetch not #buzzfetch  ul

Comment: @lbstr made good point. your script is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/m5UW7/

Comment: @user1615099 are you sure `reload(uid)` is used only one time? make some debug `function reload(uid) { alert('fire!'); ... `

Answer (score 0):

Use `on` as opposed to `click`:

```
$("#comments_option").on("click", function () {
    clearInterval(intervalId)
});
```

Because `#comments_option` is inside of `#buzzfetch ul`, the click event will only be bound to the first instance of #comments_option when using `click`. It will not bind to any further instances.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind) for further explanation on the differences between `bind` and `on`

Comment: thats not really how it works. if `#comments_option` is replaced, the click event won't fire. You would need `$('#buzzfetch').on('click', '#comments_option', function(){...});` provided that `#buzzfetch` won't be replaced and `#comments_option` is a decendant of `#buzzfetch`. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Just to be sure, I made a fiddle that demonstrates the point: http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/QRNhw/