# Disable a button after 3 clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form, with a button called add rows. I would like to disable this button after user clicks on it thrice.

Comment: Please show us your HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set a click counter on the button, but seeing as it is called "add rows", I suppose you might be able to just count the number of rows, and determine if it should be disabled that way.

```
bool disabled = true;
$('#add-rows').prop('disabled', disabled);
```

Replace `true` with your favourite means of calculating the number of rows.

Comment: dont know propt, should be attr?

Comment: I used part of your code 
`var $i = 1;
$('body').on('click','#addrow',function(){
if ($i < 2) {
 /*functions to be executed*/ 
 $i++;
} 
else {
 $(this).prop('disabled', 1);$(this).remove();
} });`

Answer (score 1):

From the top answer in google [Triple Click Event](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/triple-click-event/):

```
$.event.special.tripleclick = {

    setup: function(data, namespaces) {
        var elem = this, $elem = jQuery(elem);
        $elem.bind('click', jQuery.event.special.tripleclick.handler);
    },

    teardown: function(namespaces) {
        var elem = this, $elem = jQuery(elem);
        $elem.unbind('click', jQuery.event.special.tripleclick.handler)
    },

    handler: function(event) {
        var elem = this, $elem = jQuery(elem), clicks = $elem.data('clicks') || 0;
        clicks += 1;
        if ( clicks === 3 ) {
            clicks = 0;

            // set event type to "tripleclick"
            event.type = "tripleclick";

            // let jQuery handle the triggering of "tripleclick" event handlers
            jQuery.event.handle.apply(this, arguments)  
        }
        $elem.data('clicks', clicks);
    }

};
```

Used like so:

```
$("#mybutton").bind("tripleclick", function() {
   $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Note that you'll probably want to use `on` instead of `bind`, see [What's the difference between `on` and `live` or `bind`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind)

Comment: all the other code in that page is needed as well, in order for `tripleclick`, which is a custom event, to work.

Comment: absolutely, I thought it a bit long to copy verbatim, but I'll update the answer.

Comment: That `tripleclick` code was a little disappointing: I was hoping it was like the next thing after a `doubleclick` in the sense of firing only when there are three clicks within a short space of time, but no. (Not that a "true" tripleclick would've helped for this question.)

Comment: I like this answer, but I got the solution with lesser code. Thanks :)