# jQuery bind click function not working - jQuery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Part of my my PHP:

```
echo '<li rel="'.$rs['pic_id'].'"><a>'.$rs['name'].'</a> <a class="delete">Delete</a></li>';
```

jQuery:

```
$('#taglist li a.delete').bind('click', function(){
        pic_id = $(this).attr("rel");
        $.post('deletetag.php', pic_id, function(){
            viewtag();
          });
    });
```

The button is not working, as in it didn't get converted into a button although i clearly included the 'a' tags in the html. Where is the problem?

Comment: Well first start by changing `.bind` to `.on`

.on has replaced .bind.

Comment: is better to use `on` or `click`. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do.

```
$('#taglist li a.delete').click(function()
{
//Code Here
}));
```

Comment: Then take a look at your html output. Also use the code I gave you. If that doesn't work it's not js that's the problem it's your HTML structure.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery 1.7+

try this

```
echo '<li rel="'.$rs['pic_id'].'"><a href="#">'.$rs['name'].'</a> <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></li>';

$("#taglist li a.delete").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    pic_id = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.post('deletetag.php', pic_id, function(){
        viewtag();
    });
});
```

or

```
$("body").on("click", "#taglist li a.delete", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    pic_id = $(this).attr("rel");
    $.post('deletetag.php', pic_id, function(){
        viewtag();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried that as well, didn't work. I'm using jQuery 1.9.2 as of now.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are tryin to do but your selector is button here and the attr rel is of parent `<li>`.. so use `parent()`...

try this

```
$('#taglist li a.delete').on('click', function(){
    pic_id = $(this).parent().attr("rel");
    $.post('deletetag.php', {pic_id:pic_id}, function(){
        viewtag();
      });
});
```

and if your `<li>` is added dynamically then use on delegate event..

```
$('#taglist').on('click','li a.delete', function(){....
```

you can go through the [link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/) if you want to read more about jquery `on()`