# typeahead.js get selected datum

Tags: typeahead, typeahead.js

I'm trying to use Twitter [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) to return a datum after selection. From what I understood by the documentation the code should look something like

```
$('.selector').typeahead({
  name: 'identifier',
  local: localObjectsArray
}).on('autocompleted', function(item){
    alert(JSON.stringify(item));
});
```

However this doesn't work. What's the proper way to detect typeahead events?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After selection, so you need `typeahead:selected`:

```
$('.selector').typeahead({
    name: 'identifier',
    local: localObjectsArray
}).on('typeahead:selected', function (obj, datum) {
    console.log(obj);
    console.log(datum);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is a good tip, but should probably be edited to use .on() instead of .bind()

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind

Comment: I think using `.on()` is overkill for this, I will update the answer when `.bind()` is deprecated.

Comment: Fair enough, but just for the record, "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers" from http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: mine doesn't ever have "selected" attached so I can't use this method...been looking everywhere and can't find a solution to my issue. There seems to be so little use of typeahead.js to begin with. If you can help me here please let me know, @Hieu   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813018/twitter-typeahead-js-with-scrollto-not-working

Comment: Please note that the custom typeahead event is now `typeahead:select` instead of `typeahead:selected`. I'm unsure when this change was made, but as of v0.11.1 `typeahead.selected` isn't defined. The docs reflect this: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events