# Twitter Typeahead.js with ScrollTo not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, datatable

I have a datatable (datatables.net) with dynamically generated rows. I have a "search" box above the datatable. Right now, you can start typing in the box and i have a typeahead give options for choices of which row they want (you start typing a name and the typeahead gives you the bus stop name options, each row is based off of a bus stop in a bus schedule). Then you can select the right name you see.

As of now, selecting the bus stop in the search box does nothing. You can select by either pressing enter or clicking on the typeahead result.

What I want it to do is use scrollTo (http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html  Version 1.4.1)  to scroll to the row with that name in the datatable.

here is my code:

HTML

```
<div>
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input id="table_Search" class="tblSearch busStop span2 typeahead" type="text"></input>         
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function addTableSearch(dTable, $container, schedule, stops){
       //while the bus schedule and bus schedule stops exist
        if(schedule !==undefined && schedule.stops !== undefined){
        //getting the future stops
            var notPassed = Fp.filter(schedule.stops, function (stop) { 
                                      return !stop.passed; });
                var selector =  $container
                    .typeahead({
                        source : Fp.pluck(notPassed, 'busStopName'),
                        items  : 15
                        });
                    $('#bus-tab .dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTo(selector);

 }

addTableSearch(dTable, $('.tblSearch'), schedule.content.get(), schedule.stops);
```

i don't think I can assign "var selector" to be the typeahead, but I can't think of another way to trigger the scrollTo after selecting what you want from the typeahead.

Suggestions / help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found my solution!

```
    function addTableSearch(dTable, $container, schedule, stops){
   //while the bus schedule and bus schedule stops exist
    if(schedule !==undefined && schedule.stops !== undefined){
    //getting the future stops
        var notPassed = Fp.filter(schedule.stops, function (stop) { 
                                      return !stop.passed; 
                                  });
            var sequence;
            $container.typeahead({
                source : Fp.pluck(notPassed, 'busStopName'),
                items : 15,
                updater : function(item) {
                    // item is item selected from typeahead
                    var busStopArray = [];
                    $.each(schedule.stops, function(index, value) {
                        busStopArray[index] = value.busStopName
                                + " - " + value.sequence;
                        if (value.busStopName === item) {
                            sequence = value.sequence;
                        }
                    });

                var selector = 'tr[data-sequence="' + sequence + '"]';
                $('#firstSchedule-tab .dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTo(selector);
                $('#secondSchedule-tab .dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTo(selector);


}

addTableSearch(dTable, $('.tblSearch'), schedule.content.get(), schedule.stops);
```