# what are the differences between on() function and bind() function

Tags: jquery

on function

```
$("selector").on("click", function(event){
//code to be executed
});
```

bind function

```
$("selector").bind("click", function(event){
//code to be executed
});
```

When to use on function and bind function especially?

Comment: http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.3/jQuery.fn.bind

Comment: They are exactly the same when used in this manner (but `.on` can do much more than `.bind` when given more arguments). There is no reason to use `.bind` ever.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: RTFD... blah blah 15 characters etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind

Comment: And someone upvoted this question, really?!

Comment: <<There is no reason to use .bind ever.>> and internally .bind() use .on() so an other reason to prefer using .on()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both attaches event handlers to a document... `bind` attaches event handler directly to the elements (which does not  delegates).. so binding does not work for dynamically added element where as `on` does... it uses event delegation.

with the codes you have got.. there is no difference between `on` and `bind` here..both does the same thing (attaches click handler to the selected element)

as to  `When to use on function and bind function especially?`

simple answer would be,

> if you are using jquery 1.7+ . use `on()` ,
>   if your element is added dynamically use `.on()`.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call to .bind() occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion of event delegation in .on() or .delegate().

bind only works if the element exists, on will bind it to all elements matching the selector.
[Docs.](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```
$(document).on("click","selector", function(event){
//code applies to all elements matching the selector.
});
```

Comment: `on will bind it to all elements matching the selector.` only when given a delegate selector parameter. In the OPs case, this is not true.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you are right.