# Bind event in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have click function on a tag. I want to bind mouseover event on same element. It this possible with .bind method. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7qrC/)

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        alert(0);
    })
    $('a').bind('mouseover')
})
```

```html
<a href="#">Jitender</a>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to run the same event handler on `click` and `mouseover`?

Comment: No problem, see my answer below.

Comment: [Because of this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind) you should use `.on()` and not `.bind()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just bind the mouseover following the click binding:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    alert(0);
}).bind('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red'); // To show it working
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R7qrC/3/

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to bind the same handler to the `click` and `mouseover` event you can try this:

```
$('a').on('click mouseover', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('0');
});
```

Note the usage of `on` is preferred over `bind` in jQuery 1.7+.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('a').on('click mouseover', function() {
       alert(0);
       return false;
    });      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure!

```
$('a').mouseover(function() {
    alert("Moused!");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R7qrC/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `on` keyword.

```
$('a').on('mouseover', function() { alert(1);})
```

Per the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/):

> "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document."

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R7qrC/1/)

```
$('a').bind('mouseover', function () {
    alert(0);
});
```

Also, `bind()` is outdated, if you are using a newer version of jquery (1.7+) you should be using `on()` instead.

As it's hard to see both mouseover and click events that create an alert (since the alert from the `mouseover` would prevent you from ever clicking on it), the following will allow you to see both events working better:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/R7qrC/6/)

```
$('a').on('mouseover click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("test");
});
```