# Jquery BIND works but ON does not

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have edited my original code example to include the "right way" I should have done it

I am working on a jquery mobile project and I have noticed that if I use ON to bind a click it will work the first time the page loads but if I return to the page then I get another bind each time I return.  If I use BIND then I only get one regardless of how many times I leave the page and return.

I am fine with using BIND but I know it is going away in the future so **I would like to know why ON isn't working?**

I am using  jquery 1.9.1 and jquery mobile 1.3.1

**This code is in the head section of every page:**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
 <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('head javascript - before JQM is loaded');


    // EDITED: Don't put JQM events inside .ready()
    //$(function() {


            // *** EDITED - THIS IS CORRECT WAY TO USE .on() IN THIS CASE ****
            $(document).on("pageinit", "#page_login", function() {
                console.log('#page_login page - pageinit event -- (only once for THIS page)');
                $('#loginformSubmit').on('click', login_form_click_handler);
            });


            // *** THIS ONE WORKS ****
            $(document).on("pageinit", "#page_login", function() {
                console.log('#page_login page - pageinit event -- (only once for THIS page)');
                $('#loginformSubmit').bind('click', login_form_click_handler);
            });



           // *** BUT, if I replace the section above with this
           //          then the login_form_click_handler() function
           //          will get executed N+1 times, where N = number
           //          of times I have viewed the page. 

           $(document).on("pageinit", "#page_login", function() {
                console.log('#page_login page - pageinit event -- (only once for THIS page)');               
                /* EDITED NOTE:  This doesn't work correctly because JQM maintains
                                 a single 'document'  so each time this event is 
                                 fired (initial browse and subsequent visits if 
                                 page is not in jqm cache) I was binding another
                                 click event to the document which already had one
                                 (or more) of the same.  */
                $(document).on('click', '#loginformSubmit', function(e){                 
                     login_form_click_handler(e);
                });
           });


    //});


    <script src="resources/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

**This is the body section of the #page_login page**

```
<div data-role="page" id="page_login" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">


<div data-role="header">
    <h1>AV Login</h1>
    <a href="resources/dialogs/login_help.htm" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="b" data-rel="dialog" class="ui-btn-right">Help</a>
</div>

<div data-role="content">

<form id='loginform' class="validate" action="resources/processors/login.php" method="post">

<div data-role="popup" id="invalid_login" data-transition="pop" class="ui-content" data-theme="e" data-overlay-theme="a" style="max-width:350px;">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
Invalid username or password
</div>

<div data-role="popup" id="login_processor_error" data-transition="pop" class="ui-content" data-theme="e" data-overlay-theme="a" style="max-width:350px;">
<a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
<div id="login_processor_error_content"></div>
</div>

<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">


<li data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" data-mini="true"  class="required" />
</li>


<li data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" data-mini="true" class="required" />
</li>

</ul>

<a id="loginformSubmit" href="" data-role="button" data-mini="true">Login</a>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function login_form_click_handler(e){
    console.log('login_form_click_handler');
    e.preventDefault(); 
            // EDIT NOTE:  'this' is the #loginformSubmit element
            //        can setup your own var to use, such as:  var $this = $('#loginform');

             // .. do form validation, submission, etc ..
}
</script>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps the following thread will be helpful: [What's the difference between `on` and `live` or `bind`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind)

Comment: dont wrap your functions with `$(function()` = `.ready()` plus, `pageinite, pageshow` are jQM events, they wont work before loading JQM.

Comment: @Omar Thanks.  I moved the JQM events out of .ready()  I was thinking I wouldn't be able to use event names that basically don't exist until JQM is loaded, which doesn't happen until after this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery mobile the `document` normally stays the same through page transitions. The reason I point that out is that any time you are adding an event listener to an element (the document in this case) it is **adding** to a collection of any other event listeners already added. This is regardless of if you use `.bind` or `.on`. So every time you call `.on('click', '#loginformSubmit', ...` you are adding more listeners to that document click event.

If you change your event binding to look like this:

```
$('#loginformSubmit').on('click', login_form_click_handler);
```

You will see the same results as using `.bind` in the same fashion.

When you use the `.on` event binding syntax as you are, it's adding the event listener to the `$(document)` but will only fire your function when it bubbles up to the scoped selector `#loginformSubmit`.

[jQuery .on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: This makes total sense and I am not sure why I didn't catch that since I knew the document in a JQM site stays the same.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of .bind and .on are very different. The way you're using .on is with event delegation, and event delegation can be interrupted by events that stop propagation.

```
$('#loginformSubmit').bind('click', login_form_click_handler);
```

is equivalent to

```
$('#loginformSubmit').on('click', login_form_click_handler);
```

Though, the real problem is that you're losing `this` due to how you're calling the function. The following would probably work too, assuming the propagation isn't being stopped.

```
$(document).on('click', '#loginformSubmit', login_form_click_handler);
```

however it could result in double binding since it's bound to the document and hence will never go away unless you unbind it.