# .bind( ) Javascript not working in Firefox & IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a div that on click moves to the right, and then on click again and it goes back to the left (its a newsletter pop-out). Everything is working perfectly in Safari and Chrome, however in Firefox and IE it will only open, it won't close when you click again.  I am using .bind() and .unbind()
Any suggestions?  I am using jQuery version 1.3.2.

FF Error : **NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]**

IE Error: **SCRIPT16386: No such interface supported**

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('.newsletter').bind('click.open', open)
    $(window).resize(function () {
        var wWth = $(window).innerWidth(),
            wHgt = $(window).innerHeight();
        $('#overflow').fadeIn('slow').css({
            width: wWth,
            height: wHgt
        });
    });
});

function open() {
    var overflow = $('<div id="overflow"><div>');
    $(this).stop().animate({
        left: '-35'
    }, 650);
    if ($('#overflow').length < 1) {
        $('body').append(overflow);
    }
    var wWth = $(window).innerWidth(),
        wHgt = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('#overflow').fadeIn('slow').css({
        width: wWth,
        height: wHgt
    });
    $('.newsletter').unbind('click.open').bind('click.close', close)
}

function close(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('input')) return;
    $('#overflow').fadeOut('slow')
    $('.newsletter').stop().animate({
        left: '-390px'
    }, 650);
    $('.newsletter').unbind('click.close').bind('click.open', open)
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="newsletter_signup">
<div id="newslettertext1">
    Newsletter bestellen<br>
    <br>
    Lassen Sie sich per Newsletter &#252;ber Neuheiten und <br>
    Aktionen von Tempur informieren. Jetzt anmelden
</div>
<div id="signup">
    <form id="leftnewsletter" action="" method="get">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="emailsignup" placeholder="E-MAIL ADDRESS" style="margin-left:76px; margin-top:16px; width:187px;">
    <input type="submit" name="signupbtn" id="signupbtn" value="SIGN UP" class="signupbutton">
</form>
</div>
<div id="newslettertext2">
    *Sie k&#246;nnen jederzeit Ihre Einwilligung zum Erhalt des<br>
Newsletters zur&#252;ckziehen und sich abmelden.
</div>
```

Comment: can you share the related html also

Comment: The cause might be in broken HTML layout (incorrectly closed tags). This is the most common cause of browsers behaving differently in similar situations.

Comment: It would help to specify the jQuery version that you're using.

Comment: can you try to recreate the problem in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bWbxT/1/) it seems to be working fine in FF

Comment: @ArunPJohny i also created a fiddle which i had been using in ff and it was working fine too, its only in my actual code? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FpEZg/2/)

Comment: add few console logging statements in the handlers and see whether they are getting executed

Comment: First thing to do is to open the FF debugger to see if any js error or warning is thrown.

Comment: I am getting the error **NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]** in FF and IE

Comment: Works fine here here with jQuery 1.3.2 http://jsfiddle.net/aneSm/; FF and IE version?

Comment: Yes, it just seems to be in my actual coding, could there be a conflict or something?

Comment: It's possible; can you provide more context, other code plugins, and so on?

Comment: Theres quite a few plugins used, like **jquery.jcarousel.pack.fixed.js**, **jquery.validate.js** and so on.... it tells me the problem is with **jquery-1.3.2.min.fixed.js** when i go into firebug > console?

Comment: Can you update your old 1.3.2 jQuery core version? The validate min version is 1.6.4, for carousel I don't know

Comment: I will check with my collegue first as i know he told me before there was a reason they haven't updated jQuery version, but i can't remember, thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok let me know if the issue is related to the jQuery versione, so I'll add the comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working by simplifying the code down to:

```
$('.newsletter_signup').click(function(event) {
    if(!$(event.target).is('input')) {
        if (parseInt($(this).css('left')) == -35) {
            $(this).stop().animate({ left: '-390px' }, 650);
        } else {
            $(this).stop().animate({ left: '-35px' }, 650);
        }
    }
});
```

Works perfectly now, thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the `.on()` method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

There is [detailed post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind) in the past discussing it.

In short, `.bind()` is kept just for the compatibility purpose, we should forget it and use the more flexible `.on()` instead.

For your problem, change your `bind()` statement from:

```
$('.newsletter').bind('click.open', open)
```

into:

```
$(document).on('click', '.newsletter', open);
```

---

UPDATE:

Since you are using a very early version of jQuery, I guess the best choice you have is to use `.noConflict` to load the two versions together. jQuery has changed a LOT since 1.3. It is understandable that you might hesitate to upgrade, since your old code might have used some old functions like browser detection, etc.

So here is how you do it:

```
jqNew = jQuery.noConflict( true );
```

Then you will use `jqNew(document).on(event, selector, function);` or whatever to bind your event. The old code will continue to use `$.xxx`.

There is an example [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). Scroll that page down to the section: Example: Load two versions of jQuery (not recommended). Then, restore jQuery's globally scoped variables to the first loaded jQuery.

Comment: I was using the on/off method before bind, however i was experiencing the problem of the newsletter not opening at all? And thats why i tried using bind

Comment: Just updated the answer. You might want to consider loading a new version of jQuery beside the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Is difficult to say where the problem is, probably is somewhere in your HTML code and its manipulation.

Your sample code works on jQuery 1.3.2: http://jsfiddle.net/aneSm/

Some suggestions:

- update your jQuery core version, your plugin can't run on 1.3.2; the validate min version is 1.6.4, for carousel I don't know (...)
- check to not have any comment near a not wrapped node on which you
  use a plugin (ref. 1)
- check if you have a (direct or not) `getComputedStyle` on a DOM node
  which can't have styles (such as a text node)

**ref. 1**

```
<!-- Comment -->
<div>
    ...
</div>
```