# running Jquery Code after Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having some problems getting this part of my jQuery script to run after the Ajax – content switch…

```
/*no right click on img*/
        $('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
            return false;
/*rollover*/
        $('.roll').on('mouseenter mouseout', function() {
            var original = $(this).attr('src');
            var replacement = $(this).data('hoverimg');
            $(this).attr('src', replacement).data('hoverimg', original);
        });
        });
```

Could someone please help me get it running I tried it whit a lot of Ideas, like:

```
var init = function(){
/*Code*/
}
```

Or

```
function init(){
/*Code*/
}
```

I am a bit confused right now.

Comment: Is there any error that you get ?

Comment: Where's the ajax code? Also, your indenting is a little weird, but the code shown appears to assign the mouseenter and mouseout handlers to `.roll` _inside_ the contextmenu handler but after the `return false`, so that `.on()` statement will never run. If that's just because you've only put some of your code in the question please show a more complete sample. And please describe clearly what the desired effect is.

Comment: Did you write these events in your `AJAX` success??

Comment: You also gotta use `http://api.jquery.com/live/` to see whether  you can do your stuff after the call on DOM elements .

Comment: @TheDarkKnight - Are you aware that `.live()` was _removed_ from jQuery in v1.9? Use the delegated form of `.on()` instead (assuming a delegated handler is appropriate here, which is hard to tell from the limited description in the question).

Comment: I actually like the ajaxComplete() function, but it's hard to know what is going on here without seeing some more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one point that you make sure that if you are **binding event** on to the element that is **dynamic** then you should **reference** it through some static data which is already on the page like **body** or **document**.
Example :

```
        $('body').bind('contextmenu','img', function(e) {
            return false;
            /*rollover*/
        $('body').on('mouseenter mouseout','.roll', function() {
            var original = $(this).attr('src');
            var replacement = $(this).data('hoverimg');
            $(this).attr('src', replacement).data('hoverimg', original);
        });
        });
```

Try running it now. It will definitely work.

Comment: Pleasure is mine my friend.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you need to bind this only on ajax success.  Then you can try [**binding**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) and [**unbinding**](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) in jQuery.

*unbind before calling the ajax and bind it back in the success callback of ajax.*

However I would prefer to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [**.off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/) event handler attachments.

See this [**SO answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind) for *.on VS .live VS .bind*