# Jquery copyed html class with specific index unable to identify click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi  every one i am new to JQuery.i have a problem with click event.i am taken `temearea_div` as a container when ever `rightclick` passing an argument(classname) with that clearfunction is executed and copy Html content into `tempaarea_div` .i had a problem while click a class with specific index. click is not identifying.could any one solve my problem. how to give selector to identify click with specific index.thanks in advance

THis is My Html Code

```
 <div class="temparea_div"> 
 <img src="img/Img_01.png"/>
 </div>
    <div class="Maintain_submenu_nav_02" style="display: none;">
    <div class="maintainence_image_02"></div>
    <div class="maintainence_image_02" style=" left: 22.2%;top: 32.7%;"></div>
    <div class="maintainence_image_02" style="top: 35.7%;top:42.7%"></div>
    <div class="maintainence_image_02" style="top: 35.7%;top:53.7%"></div>
    <img src="img/Img_02.png"/>    
 </div>
```

My JQuery Code

```
$('.rightclick').bind(function(){

    clearfunction('Maintain_submenu_nav_02');
});   

var clearfunction=function(e){
    $(".temparea_div").empty();
     $('.'+e).show();
      $(".temparea_div").html($('.'+e).html());
      $('.'+e).hide();

};
```

this is not identidentiding click

```
$('.maintainence_image_02:eq(1)').bind('click', function() {
            $('.maintainence_image_02:eq(1)').css("border", "1px solid #00FFFF");
            maintaincesubmenu = true;
        });
```

i used this one but when click temparea_div then .maintainence_image_02:eq(1) calling

```
 $('.temparea_div').bind('click','.maintainence_image_02:eq(1)', function() {
        $('.maintainence_image_02:eq(1)').css("border", "1px solid #00FFFF");
        maintaincesubmenu = true;
    });
```

Comment: Use  :  $('.rightclick')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('.temparea_div').on('click','.maintainence_image_02:eq(1)', function() {
    $('.maintainence_image_02:eq(1)').css("border", "1px solid #00FFFF");
    maintaincesubmenu = true;
});
```

Comment: hay this working .. but tell me  what is difference between bind and on .i think on event is for jQuery1.8 after. how do i get for previous versions.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind

Comment: The idea for adding .on() was to create a unified event API, rather than having multiple functions for binding event;

Answer (score 0):

If rightclick is class then :

```
$('.rightclick').bind(function(){

    clearfunction('Maintain_submenu_nav_02');
});
```

Comment: it is class it is calling .but unable to identify copied html class with specific index