# Works in jsfiddle but it wont work in dreamweaver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I have read that I have to put back in the event handler for it to work in dreamweaver from JS Fiddle, I have put it back in and I it still wont work? Here is the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EfLJJ/6/

Here is my JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".list .fs1").bind({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(".sublist").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(".sublist").hide();
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery do you use? is it loaded?

Comment: Check console for errors.

Comment: Maybe you dont attach jQuery library in Dreamweaver

Comment: I am not sure I don't code in jQuery, this answer was given too me as part of a question on here. How can I check what version I am running?

Comment: On the browser check the page code, or open the console. Or look in your script if you have this: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` otherwise add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! To get it running in Dreamweaver you have to use the Javascript Script Tags

Javascript:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Your Code Here */
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the jQuery library to your script.

Put this code inside the `<head>` tags of your page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have put the script in the meta tags is this right? If this is right it still doesn't work?

<head>
<meta <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Transition Box</title>
<style type="text/css">

Comment: @fudgematico sorry, I am tired! I meant inside the __head__ tags: `<head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> `</head>`

Answer (score 0):

In your html code inside head put this line of code in order to include the jQuery library:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Otherwise will not be able to use it.

In jsfiddle this works in a different way.

Comment: This still doesn't work I have added the follow:
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Transition box.js"></script>
      The "Transitionbox.js" uses the same code that I posted at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you're using jQuery version 1.7 and above, I'd recommend you switch from using ".bind()" to ".on()" for as ".on()" is the preferred method according to the jquery website. Check out the difference between ".bind()", ".on()" and ".live()" for more info here, [What's the difference between `on` and `live` or `bind`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065305/whats-the-difference-between-on-and-live-or-bind)

Comment: That doesn't work either? Any suggestions? This code is sat below my CSS code and is in the <head>? <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".list .fs1").on({
    mouseenter:function(){
        $(".sublist").show();
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(".sublist").hide();
 }
    });
});
</script>