# What are the "native DOM events" mentioned in the jQuery manual?

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-events, native

In the jQuery manual, about the `bind()` function, it is said that there are some "native DOM events" (with 2 examples).

Where can I find the complete list documented?

For example, I am implementing an `onShow` event. How can I find out if such an event already exists?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924173/looking-for-a-full-list-of-jquery-event-types

Comment: The answer there is applicable to this one, but technically that question is limited to jQuery-supported events, whereas the OP wants to know about all DOM-supported events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current standard. See: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html (scroll down a ways). For DOM Level 3 (still in working draft, but may be implemented in some browsers), see: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/

If you're solely worried about stepping on the toes of default events, go with the DOM Level 3 working draft. It includes everything currently in DOM Level 2, and additional ones that may eventually make it to spec.