# Full list of events that can be bind()/on()/live(),jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I am new to jQuery, and I know I can set an handler for click event using below way:

```
$('#foo').bind('click', handler);
```

or

```
$('#foo').click(handler);
```

here, we can see there are a method `click` corresponding to an event "click". I can see all the jQuery event methods which can be rigistered are listed here http://api.jquery.com/category/events/ according to [Looking for a full list of jQuery event types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924173/looking-for-a-full-list-of-jquery-event-types)

While there are some events that I can use `on()` method to bind while I can't find in that method category , for example I **can't** find an `input` method corresponding to "**input**" event while I do can:

```
$('#inputId').on('input',function(e){
     alert('Changed!')
 });
```

## Question

1. Are all the events corresponding to jQuery's event method are the subset of the event that I can use `on()` to bind?
2. What are the full event list that I can bind to using jQuery's `on` method, are they https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events ?

Comment: They're any event that the browser knows about.

Comment: These methods, such as `.click`, are there for convenience, and are just aliases of `.on(name...)`, there is no guarantee that all DOM events have a jQuery alias.

Comment: @Barmar, where can I find the full event list which browser know about?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to any event that the browser supports on DOM elements. The page you linked to contains all the standard DOM events, but browsers might supply their own implementation-dependent events as well. For instance, that page also has a section titled **Mozilla-specific events**. For other browsers, you would have to find their developer documentation.

If you can bind the event using the native `addEventListener` method in Javascript, you can bind it using `.on()` in jQuery.

Comment: Do you mean the first section "Standard events" of the link I post can be bind to all browsers using `.on()` in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I find this script works for both Chrome, Firefox and IE11

```
function getEventList(dom) {
    return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(dom).concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(dom)))).filter(function (i) {
        return !i.indexOf('on') && (dom[i] == null || typeof dom[i] == 'function');
    })
}
```